# Unexpected identifier char[32]

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

So i am having an unexpected identifier error in vs 2017.
The error list indicates that this piece of code is the problem:

```
NETVAR("CBaseAttributableItem", "m_szCustomName", GetCustomName, char [32]);
```

the char[32] part is the one underlined in red.
Thx
EDIT: 
I also get

```
syntax error: '['
```

and

```
unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

alright since i cant post this much code without typing im just explain some stuff here NETVAR is used to get addresses of variables in games like health for modification or just reading them. If you need anything elses definition
do ask me in the comments also though since it is a syntax error the codes meaning may not be much *Idk im kinda new* so yeah
Also im using Vs 2017 with toolkit v141 and sdk 10.0.17763.0

```
#pragma once
#include "../../dependencies/math/math.hpp"
#include <array>
#include "collideable.hpp"
#include "client_class.hpp"
#include "../../dependencies/utilities/netvar_manager.hpp"
#include <string.h>

enum move_type {
    movetype_none = 0,
    movetype_isometric,
    movetype_walk,
    movetype_step,
    movetype_fly,
    movetype_flygravity,
    movetype_vphysics,
    movetype_push,
    movetype_noclip,
    movetype_ladder,
    movetype_observer,
    movetype_custom,
    movetype_last = movetype_custom,
    movetype_max_bits = 4,
    max_movetype
};

enum entity_flags {
    fl_onground = (1 << 0),
    fl_ducking = (1 << 1),
    fl_waterjump = (1 << 2),
    fl_ontrain = (1 << 3),
    fl_inrain = (1 << 4),
    fl_frozen = (1 << 5),
    fl_atcontrols = (1 << 6),
    fl_client = (1 << 7),
    fl_fakeclient = (1 << 8),
    fl_inwater = (1 << 9),
    fl_fly = (1 << 10),
    fl_swim = (1 << 11),
    fl_conveyor = (1 << 12),
    fl_npc = (1 << 13),
    fl_godmode = (1 << 14),
    fl_notarget = (1 << 15),
    fl_aimtarget = (1 << 16),
    fl_partialground = (1 << 17),
    fl_staticprop = (1 << 18),
    fl_graphed = (1 << 19),
    fl_grenade = (1 << 20),
    fl_stepmovement = (1 << 21),
    fl_donttouch = (1 << 22),
    fl_basevelocity = (1 << 23),
    fl_worldbrush = (1 << 24),
    fl_object = (1 << 25),
    fl_killme = (1 << 26),
    fl_onfire = (1 << 27),
    fl_dissolving = (1 << 28),
    fl_transragdoll = (1 << 29),
    fl_unblockable_by_player = (1 << 30)
};
enum item_definition_indexes {
    WEAPON_NONE = 0,
    WEAPON_DEAGLE,
    WEAPON_ELITE,
    WEAPON_FIVESEVEN,
    WEAPON_GLOCK,
    WEAPON_AK47 = 7,
    WEAPON_AUG,
    WEAPON_AWP,
    WEAPON_FAMAS,
    WEAPON_G3SG1,
    WEAPON_GALILAR = 13,
    WEAPON_M249,
    WEAPON_M4A1 = 16,
    WEAPON_MAC10,
    WEAPON_P90 = 19,
    WEAPON_MP5SD = 23,
    WEAPON_UMP45,
    WEAPON_XM1014,
    WEAPON_BIZON,
    WEAPON_MAG7,
    WEAPON_NEGEV,
    WEAPON_SAWEDOFF,
    WEAPON_TEC9,
    WEAPON_TASER,
    WEAPON_HKP2000,
    WEAPON_MP7,
    WEAPON_MP9,
    WEAPON_NOVA,
    WEAPON_P250,
    WEAPON_SHIELD,
    WEAPON_SCAR20,
    WEAPON_SG556,
    WEAPON_SSG08,
    WEAPON_KNIFEGG,
    WEAPON_KNIFE,
    WEAPON_FLASHBANG,
    WEAPON_HEGRENADE,
    WEAPON_SMOKEGRENADE,
    WEAPON_MOLOTOV,
    WEAPON_DECOY,
    WEAPON_INCGRENADE,
    WEAPON_C4,
    WEAPON_HEALTHSHOT = 57,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_T = 59,
    WEAPON_M4A1_SILENCER,
    WEAPON_USP_SILENCER,
    WEAPON_CZ75A = 63,
    WEAPON_REVOLVER,
    WEAPON_TAGRENADE = 68,
    WEAPON_FISTS,
    WEAPON_BREACHCHARGE,
    WEAPON_TABLET = 72,
    WEAPON_MELEE = 74,
    WEAPON_AXE,
    WEAPON_HAMMER,
    WEAPON_SPANNER = 78,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_GHOST = 80,
    WEAPON_FIREBOMB,
    WEAPON_DIVERSION,
    WEAPON_FRAG_GRENADE,
    WEAPON_SNOWBALL,
    WEAPON_BUMPMINE,
    WEAPON_BAYONET = 500,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_FLIP = 505,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_GUT,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_KARAMBIT,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_M9_BAYONET,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_TACTICAL,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_FALCHION = 512,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_SURVIVAL_BOWIE = 514,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_BUTTERFLY,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_PUSH,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_URSUS = 519,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_GYPSY_JACKKNIFE,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_STILETTO = 522,
    WEAPON_KNIFE_WIDOWMAKER
};

class entity_t {
public:
    void* animating() {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(uintptr_t(this) + 0x4);
    }
    void* networkable() {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(uintptr_t(this) + 0x8);
    }
    collideable_t* collideable() {
        using original_fn = collideable_t * (__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[3](this);
    }
    c_client_class* client_class() {
        using original_fn = c_client_class * (__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)networkable())[2](networkable());
    }

    int index() {
        using original_fn = int(__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)networkable())[10](networkable());
    }
    bool is_player() {
        using original_fn = bool(__thiscall*)(entity_t*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[155](this);
    }
    bool is_weapon() {
        using original_fn = bool(__thiscall*)(entity_t*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[163](this);
    }
    vec3_t get_absolute_origin() {
        __asm {
            MOV ECX, this
            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS : [ECX]
            CALL DWORD PTR DS : [EAX + 0x28]
        }
    }
    bool setup_bones(matrix_t* out, int max_bones, int mask, float time) {
        if (!this) {
            return false;
        }

        using original_fn = bool(__thiscall*)(void*, matrix_t*, int, int, float);
        return (*(original_fn**)animating())[13](animating(), out, max_bones, mask, time);
    }
    model_t* model() {
        using original_fn = model_t * (__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)animating())[8](animating());
    }
    void update() {
        using original_fn = void(__thiscall*)(entity_t*);
        (*(original_fn**)this)[218](this);
    }
    int draw_model(int flags, uint8_t alpha) {
        using original_fn = int(__thiscall*)(void*, int, uint8_t);
        return (*(original_fn**)animating())[9](animating(), flags, alpha);
    }
    void set_angles(vec3_t angles) {
        using original_fn = void(__thiscall*)(void*, const vec3_t&);
        static original_fn set_angles_fn = (original_fn)((DWORD)utilities::pattern_scan(GetModuleHandleA("client_panorama.dll"), "55 8B EC 83 E4 F8 83 EC 64 53 56 57 8B F1"));
        set_angles_fn(this, angles);
    }
    void set_position(vec3_t position) {
        using original_fn = void(__thiscall*)(void*, const vec3_t&);
        static original_fn set_position_fn = (original_fn)((DWORD)utilities::pattern_scan(GetModuleHandleA("client_panorama.dll"), "55 8B EC 83 E4 F8 51 53 56 57 8B F1 E8"));
        set_position_fn(this, position);
    }
    vec3_t &get_world_space_center() {
        vec3_t vec_origin = origin();

        vec3_t min = this->collideable()->mins() + vec_origin;
        vec3_t max = this->collideable()->maxs() + vec_origin;

        vec3_t size = max - min;
        size /= 2.f;
        size += min;

        return size;
    }
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_fFlags", flags, int);
    OFFSET(bool, dormant, 0xED);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseEntity", "m_hOwnerEntity", owner_handle, unsigned long);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_flSimulationTime", simulation_time, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_vecOrigin", origin, vec3_t);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_vecViewOffset[0]", view_offset, vec3_t);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_iTeamNum", team, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseEntity", "m_bSpotted", spotted, bool);
};

class econ_view_item_t {
public:
    NETVAR("DT_ScriptCreatedItem", "m_bInitialized", is_initialized, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_ScriptCreatedItem", "m_iEntityLevel", entity_level, int);
    NETVAR("DT_ScriptCreatedItem", "m_iAccountID", account_id, int);
    NETVAR("DT_ScriptCreatedItem", "m_iItemIDLow", item_id_low, int);

};

class base_view_model : public entity_t {
public:
    NETVAR("DT_BaseViewModel", "m_nModelIndex", model_index, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseViewModel", "m_nViewModelIndex", view_model_index, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseViewModel", "m_hWeapon", m_hweapon, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseViewModel", "m_hOwner", m_howner, int);
};

class attributable_item_t : public entity_t {
public:
    NETVAR("DT_BaseViewModel", "m_nModelIndex", model_index, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_OriginalOwnerXuidLow", original_owner_xuid_low, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_OriginalOwnerXuidHigh", original_owner_xuid_high, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_szCustomName", fallback_name, char[32]);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_nFallbackStatTrak", fallback_stattrak, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_nFallbackPaintKit", fallback_paint_kit, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_nFallbackSeed", fallback_seed, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_iEntityQuality", entity_quality, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_flFallbackWear", fallback_wear, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_hWeaponWorldModel", world_model_handle, unsigned long);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_iItemDefinitionIndex", item_definition_index, short);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_iItemIDHigh", item_id_high, int); //jakby crash to wez offset z hazedumpera

    econ_view_item_t& item() {
        return *(econ_view_item_t*)this;
    }
};

class weapon_t : public entity_t {
public:
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_flNextPrimaryAttack", next_primary_attack, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_flNextSecondaryAttack", next_secondary_attack, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_iClip1", clip1_count, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_iClip2", clip2_count, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_iPrimaryReserveAmmoCount", primary_reserve_ammo_acount, int);
    NETVAR("DT_WeaponCSBase", "m_flRecoilIndex", recoil_index, float);
    NETVAR("DT_WeaponCSBaseGun", "m_zoomLevel", zoom_level, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseAttributableItem", "m_iItemDefinitionIndex", item_definition_index, short);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseCombatWeapon", "m_iEntityQuality", entity_quality, int);

    float get_innacuracy() {
        using original_fn = float(__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[476](this);
    }

    float get_spread() {
        using original_fn = float(__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[446](this);
    }

    void update_accuracy_penalty() {
        using original_fn = void(__thiscall*)(void*);
        (*(original_fn**)this)[477](this);
    }
    weapon_info_t* get_weapon_data() {
        using original_fn = weapon_info_t * (__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[454](this); //skinchanger crash
    }
};

class player_t : public entity_t {
private:
    template <typename T>
    T& read(uintptr_t offset) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) + offset);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void write(uintptr_t offset, T data) {
        *reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) + offset) = data;
    }

public:
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_hViewModel[0]", view_model, int); //tutaj
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bHasDefuser", has_defuser, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bGunGameImmunity", has_gun_game_immunity, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_iShotsFired", shots_fired, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_angEyeAngles", eye_angles, vec3_t); //"DT_CSPlayer->m_angEyeAngles[0]");
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_ArmorValue", armor, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bHasHelmet", has_helmet, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bIsScoped", is_scoped, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bIsDefusing", is_defusing, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_iAccount", money, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_flLowerBodyYawTarget", lower_body_yaw, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_flNextAttack", next_attack, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_flFlashDuration", flash_duration, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_flFlashMaxAlpha", flash_alpha, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bHasNightVision", m_bHasNightVision, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bNightVisionOn", m_bNightVisionOn, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_iHealth", health, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_lifeState", life_state, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_fFlags", flags, int);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_viewPunchAngle", punch_angle, vec3_t);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_aimPunchAngle", aim_punch_angle, vec3_t);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_vecVelocity[0]", velocity, vec3_t);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_flMaxspeed", max_speed, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BaseEntity", "m_flShadowCastDistance", m_flFOVTime, float);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_hObserverTarget", observer_target, unsigned long);
    NETVAR("DT_BasePlayer", "m_nHitboxSet", hitbox_set, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_flDuckAmount", duck_amount, float);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_bHasHeavyArmor", has_heavy_armor, bool);
    NETVAR("DT_PlantedC4", "m_flC4Blow", c4_blow_time, float);
    NETVAR("DT_SmokeGrenadeProjectile", "m_nSmokeEffectTickBegin", smoke_grenade_tick_begin, int);
    NETVAR("DT_CSPlayer", "m_nTickBase", get_tick_base, int);

    weapon_t* active_weapon() {
        auto active_weapon = read<DWORD>(netvar_manager::get_net_var(netvar_manager::fnv::hash("DT_CSPlayer"), netvar_manager::fnv::hash("m_hActiveWeapon"))) & 0xFFF;
        return reinterpret_cast<weapon_t*>(interfaces::entity_list->get_client_entity(active_weapon));
    }

    bool has_c4() {
        static auto ret = reinterpret_cast<bool(__thiscall*)(void*)>(utilities::pattern_scan(GetModuleHandleA("client_panorama.dll"), "56 8B F1 85 F6 74 31"));
        return ret(this);
    }

    vec3_t get_eye_pos() {
        return origin() + view_offset(); //hazedumper
    }

    bool can_see_player_pos(player_t* player, const vec3_t& pos) {
        trace_t tr;
        ray_t ray;
        trace_filter filter;
        filter.skip = this;

        auto start = get_eye_pos();
        auto dir = (pos - start).normalized();

        ray.initialize(start, pos);
        interfaces::trace_ray->trace_ray(ray, MASK_SHOT | CONTENTS_GRATE, &filter, &tr);

        return tr.entity == player || tr.flFraction > 0.97f;
    }

    vec3_t get_bone_position(int bone) {
        matrix_t bone_matrices[128];
        if (setup_bones(bone_matrices, 128, 256, 0.0f))
            return vec3_t{ bone_matrices[bone][0][3], bone_matrices[bone][1][3], bone_matrices[bone][2][3] };
        else
            return vec3_t{ };
    }

    vec3_t get_hitbox_position(player_t* entity, int hitbox_id) {
        matrix_t bone_matrix[MAXSTUDIOBONES];

        if (entity->setup_bones(bone_matrix, MAXSTUDIOBONES, BONE_USED_BY_HITBOX, 0.0f)) {
            auto studio_model = interfaces::model_info->get_studio_model(entity->model());

            if (studio_model) {
                auto hitbox = studio_model->hitbox_set(0)->hitbox(hitbox_id);

                if (hitbox) {
                    auto min = vec3_t{}, max = vec3_t{};

                    math.transform_vector(hitbox->mins, bone_matrix[hitbox->bone], min);
                    math.transform_vector(hitbox->maxs, bone_matrix[hitbox->bone], max);

                    return vec3_t((min.x + max.x) * 0.5f, (min.y + max.y) * 0.5f, (min.z + max.z) * 0.5f);
                }
            }
        }
        return vec3_t{};
    }

    bool is_enemy() {
        static auto danger_zone = interfaces::console->get_convar("game_type");

        if (!is_in_local_team() || danger_zone->get_int() == 6)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool is_in_local_team() {
        return utilities::call_virtual<bool(__thiscall*)(void*)>(this, 92)(this);
    }

    bool is_alive() {
        return life_state() == 0;
    }

    bool is_moving() {
        if (this->velocity().length() > 0.1f)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    bool is_in_air() {
        if (this->flags() & fl_onground)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    bool is_flashed() {
        if (this->flash_duration() > 0.0f)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    void update_client_side_animations() {
        using original_fn = void(__thiscall*)(void*);
        (*(original_fn**)this)[221](this);
    }

    vec3_t & abs_origin() {
        using original_fn = vec3_t & (__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[10](this);;
    }
    vec3_t & abs_angles() {
        using original_fn = vec3_t & (__thiscall*)(void*);
        return (*(original_fn**)this)[11](this);;
    }
    int move_type() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<int*> (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) + 0x25C); //hazedumper
    }
    vec3_t eye_pos() {
        vec3_t ret;
        utilities::call_virtual<void(__thiscall*)(void*, vec3_t&)>(this, 281)(this, ret); // this is the real eye pos
        return ret;
    }

    int* weapons() { //tu jesli skinchanger
        return reinterpret_cast<int*> (uintptr_t(this) + 0x2DF8);
    } 
};
```

Header file with netvar func:

```
#define NETVAR(table, prop, func_name, type) \
        type& func_name( ) { \
          static uintptr_t offset = 0; \
          if(!offset) \
          { offset = netvar_manager::get_net_var(netvar_manager::fnv::hash( table ), netvar_manager::fnv::hash( prop ) ); } \
          \
          return *reinterpret_cast< type* >( uintptr_t( this ) + offset ); \
        }

    #define NETVAR_PTR(table, prop, func_name, type) \
        type* func_name( ) { \
          static uintptr_t offset = 0; \
          if(!offset) \
          { offset = netvar_manager::get_net_var(netvar_manager::fnv::hash( table ), netvar_manager::fnv::hash( prop ) ); } \
          \
          return reinterpret_cast< type* >( uintptr_t( this ) + offset ); \
        }

    #define OFFSET(type, var, offset) \
        type& var() { \
            return *(type*)(uintptr_t(this) + offset); \
        } \
```

Edit 2: I removed the [32] and it compiled just fine however the program itself didnt work

Comment: Firstly, "underlined in red" is not an "error". Errors are reported by the compiler when when you compile your code. Have you tried to compile it? What did the compiler say? Secondly, most likely `NETVAR` is a macro. Provide the definition for the macro.

Comment: NETVAR gets the addresses for variables such as health in video games. mainly used for game hacking

Comment: Without the source for `NETVAR` we won't be able to help you. We also need to see the code around where you're using it.

Comment: alright one sec

Comment: also i think it might have something to do with the bracketsin    char[]

Comment: @fr06t we actually need to see the definition of `NETVAR` in the header. That doesn't seem to be a commonly available toolkit.

Comment: going to sleep guys hopefully ill have an answer probably not ill probably delete the post if not but thx

Answer (score 1):

So as suspected the issue is in how `NETVAR` is defined:

```
type& func_name( ) { \
```

This line will try to return `char[32]` which is not a valid return type for a method. Removing the `[32]` doesn't fix it either because that loses the fact you actually need a pointer to the variable as what you want back isn't a `char` but `char*`. You can try `NETVAR_PTR` which might work and return the right value but you need to pass `char` instead of `char[32]` to the `type` parameter. That will return `char*` and you'll have to be careful to never write more than 31 characters and maintain the null terminator yourself.

It's worth noting that this is all very ABI dependent and don't be surprised if this breaks because ABI is not the most stable thing on Windows.

It's worth noting that some cleaver template programming could fix the return type issue using type traits:

```
std::conditional_t<std::is_array_v<type>, std::decay_t<type>, type> func_name \
```

This conditionally is either a pointer or whatever type originally passed depending on if it's an array or not.